# How to convert 2 digit CNT codes or full CNT names to 3 digit CNT codes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, iso, navicat, country-codes

I have a `MySQL` database table that contains a column named `Country`. Sometimes it's a full `CNT` name, sometimes `ISO 3` or `ISO 2`. CNT code is depending on the source file used for this table. The country names are always written in uppercase (*CANADA, POLAND etc*.).

I need to add some statement into my query what would convert the country `name` or country `ISO 3` code to the `ISO 2` CNT code - (*CA, PL etc.*).

I tried to use an easy solution:

`select left (Country, 2) from tb_name`

This is not useful for all countries. If I will take only the first two left letters from *'POLAND'* then I will get *'PO'* instead of *'PL'*.

I will really appreciate any advice from you.

Answer (score 0):

As you have inconsistent names in the column, I would recommend having a lookup table like the one below:

```
countries
country_name | country_code
POLAND       | PL
POL          | PL
CANADA       | CA
```

`country_name` can be a primary key (and you can add more names as they appear in your other table) and `country_code` can be an ISO country code.

Once this is done, you can use `JOIN` in your queries to always get `counry_code` from this table.

Answer (score 0):

You will need another table, like

```
CuntryISO2  CountryISO3 CountryName
PL          POL         POLAND
IT          ITA         ITALY
```

Then you can join your table with this one, with a join like

```
on  myTab.Country = case(when length(myTab.Country) = 2 then CountryISO2
                         when length(myTab.Country) = 3 then CountryISO3
                         else CountryName end)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Start by extracting the non-2 digit codes in your data:

```
select distinct country
from t
where length(country) <> 2
group by country;
```

Then, load this into a spreadsheet and add the two-digit code in a separate column.  Wikipedia should be a fine source for the 2-digit country code.

Then you can either create a giant case statement or a table for update purposes.

But you need to begin by having the right assignment.

Comment: wouldnt be better use the wikipedia info to create a table in the db, and then update the column there?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . Only if you assume that the names are correctly and fully spelled out.